# Google Translate js is not working in ie but its working on chrom,edge and firefox

Tags: javascript, .net, xmlhttprequest, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am using google widget which use js provided by google.
Its working on chrome,mozila and edge but only problem is there with IE, its not showing widget itself :(
I am using below code.

```
             <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
     </script>  
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function googleTranslateElementInit() {
             new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: "en,fr"}, 'google_translate_element');
         }
     </script> 
 <div align="right" id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: Microsoft Edge was published in January of 2015, more than six years ago. At which point do we forget about IE? I cannot fault anybody for using code that's no longer compatible with a six year old, dead browser.

Comment: @ChrisG It is related to the introduction of support for HTTP Strict Transport Security standard (HSTS) in IE11, included in security update KB 3058515.